# Can't install driver using libpcan

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instructions on the libpcan ROS page however when I entered 'sudo ./install_pcan.sh' I got the following error: sudo: ./install_pcan.sh: command not found. http://wiki.ros.org/libpcan

I'm trying to work out which ROS package I can use to communicate with 2 Schunk Powercube arms via canbus. I have tried using the available schunk packages however I believe that our arms are so old that existing packages do not support them. Therefore looking to start from scratch.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228245/can%27t-install-driver-using-libpcan/) by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Their installation instructions look very out of date (they're still using rosmake).

Drivers for the PEAK CAN adapters are now included in the Linux kernel, and using them through [SocketCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN) is simpler and more portable than using the proprietary drivers.

The wikipedia article describes how to use the virtual can interface. For a real interface, you don't need to create the interface, but you do need set the bit rate and enable the interface manually. You can do this with the following commands:

```
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
sudo ip link set can0 up
```

**OR** you can make it autoconfigure by adding the following interface configuration to your `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug can0
iface can0 inet manual
    pre-up ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gracecopplestone](https://answers.ros.org/users/26005/gracecopplestone/) on 2016-03-04**:
Thanks, out of interest why do you specify bitrate as opposed to baudrate? We've been using a baudrate of 500 up until now.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-04**:
The `ip` command uses the `bitrate` keyword for setting the CAN bit rate. This is documented in the Linux kernel documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt (baud rate and bit rate refer to the same thing on CAN)